# Markov chain and computing the expected number for fixed absorbing state

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose I am given a state space $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$ with transition probability matrix

$\mathbf{P}= \begin{bmatrix}
     \ 1 & \ 0 & 0 & 0        \\[0.3em]
     \frac{1}{2} & 0        & \frac{1}{2} & 0\\[0.3em]
     \ 0 & \frac{1}{2}\ & 0 &\frac{1}{2}\ \\[0.3em]
     0 & 0 & 0 & 1
   \end{bmatrix}$

0 and 3 are absorbing states

So I want to compute $E(X_T=0 \ given \ that  X_0=1)$

I know how to compute  $E(X_T\ given \ that  X_0=1)$ using the fist step analysis.

However, in this case, absorbing state is fixed and computing the second one is the expected value of being absorbed in either 0 or 3 given we start at 1

How can I compute the first case?

Comment: $\{X_T=0\}$ is not a random variable but an event and thus cannot have an expectation. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Almost surely (LOL) you have mis-read the problem, which meant to ask fof $P(X_T = 0 | X_0 = 1)$, the probability, not the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume here $T$ is the first time that the system hits one of the two absorbing states. Then the desired quantity can be computed using a boundary value problem: the basic recipe (implied by the total probability formula applied to conditioning on the first step) is

$$(Lq)(x)=0,x \not \in A \cup B \\
q(x)=1,x \in A \\
q(x)=0,x \in B$$

where $q(x)$ is the probability to hit $A$ before hitting $B$ starting at $x$ (and is written as a column vector), $L=P-I$, $P$ is the transition probability matrix. In finite state space Markov chains, this gives a system of linear equations that can be solved using ordinary linear system methods. Your desired quantity is $q(1)$.